# ORACLE: alternative to AND operator

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement

Instead of using comparison:

```
IF column1=value1 AND column2=value2 THEN ...
```

I want something similar to:

```
IF (column1, column2) = (value1, value2) THEN ...
```

Comment: Why? Does the existing operator not serve the purpose?

Comment: @shahkalpesh - I don't know what reason the OP had to ask this question, but to me it seems logical that "relational" (whatever) (in this case, relational databases) should support equality of tuples. My reply to your "Why" is "Why not"?

Comment: Question... Are you specifically interested in an `IF` statement (and therefore PL/SQL, rather than Oracle SQL)? I posted an answer that applies to SQL, but not to PL/SQL...  then I re-read your post and I see you are asking about `IF... THEN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason which eludes me, Oracle doesn't support that syntax (even though tuples is the central concept of relational theory, and therefore of relational databases!) It would make perfect sense to be able to use the syntax you show.

Something not very different is available (but only in SQL!)

```
select 1 as result 
from   dual
where  (3, 5) in ((3,5))
;

RESULT
------
     1
```

That is: use an `IN` condition (even with a single member on the right-hand side). This works for tuples in all dimensions.

Comment: I want use the structure in a "select...case when..then..." with 2 condition. The 2 conditions use the same select but return 2 columns values. To use only one select i need to use one structure similar to "(column1,column2)=(value1,value2)".

Comment: @PeterRoman - that is *exactly* how the `IN` condition works - perhaps even simpler than you think. `case when (column1, column2) in (select value1, value2 from some_table) then ... [else ... ] end`. Note that in this case you don't even have specific tuples on the right-hand side of `IN` - you have a subquery.